# Возникает ошибка при неявном приведении типов

Tags: c++, типы-данных

Есть два класса `A` и `B`, в классе `A` нет определения `<<`, но есть в классе `B`. Не хочет неявно приводить тип `A` к типу `B`, хотя, по идее, всё нормально. В чём проблема?

```
...
class B; 
class A
{
    public:
        friend class B;
        A(B& s_,...):s(s_),... {} // Конструктор с параметром типа B&
        ...
        operator B const& () const {return s;} // <-- приведение
        operator B& () {return s;} // <-- приведение
    private:
        B& s; 
        ...
 };
class B
{
    public:
        ... // всякие конструкторы и функции
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream &os, B const &s) 
        {
            ... // не вызывает подозрений
            return os;
        }
        friend class A;
        A operator [] (B const &s2) // метод, для которого и нужен класс A
        {
            ...
            return A(*this,...);
        }
}
```

В `main` пишу такое:

```
B s(...),s1(...);
cout << s[s1]; // <-- ошибка в этой строке
```

Появляется ошибка

> [Error] cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}'
>   lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream&&'

Что интересно, если написать явное приведение, то всё норм:

```
cout << (B const& ) s[s1]; // <-- ошибки нет
```

P.s.: проблема именно в приведении, т.к. я написал `<<` специально для `A` и всё работало.

Comment: @Abyx
Всё делается для метода этого. Просто до конца не ясно, какой тип возвращать и всё такое

Comment: Это очень не безопасно кастить классы, которые не являются наследниками друг друга. Что будет если вы добавите в class A ещё члены или виртуальную функцию. Вы скорее всего получите неправильное поведение.

Comment: @Abyx Что именно? Реализацию `<<`?

Comment: @mark113 Скиньте сюда минимальный компилируемый (во всем кроме ошибки с ostream) кусок кода, который воспроизводит данную проблему.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive слишком много писать, да и не имеет особого смысла, так как все остальные части протестированы и работают нормально. Для этого мне нужно скинуть конструкторы (оба вызывают по несколько больших функций), реализацию метода, вводить все данные класса. Думаю, это скорее помешает

Comment: @mark113 Вы можете создать тестовый проект, в котором вырезать все, кроме необходимых для воспроизведение ошибки частей (сделать везде заглушки, а не относящееся к проблеме вообще снести), который будет компилироваться при этом (т.е. без всяких `...` в коде) не считая ошибки, указанной вами в вопросе.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive я описал только минимум, нужный для инструкции `cout << s[s1];`. Как я это скомпилирую без конструкторов, `[]`, всех данных и `<<`?

Comment: @mark113 Например, [вот так](http://ideone.com/QWWqWx). Вынесите `ostream& operator << (ostream &os, B const &s)`  из класса `B`.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive код по ссылке не компилируется

Comment: @mark113 Вот именно, и я написал что требуется сделать, чтобы он скомпилировался. Например, вот [так](http://ideone.com/mbbTYq).

Comment: @StateItPrimitive скомпилилось! Спасибо! Так а в чём проблема тогда? Какая разница, где `<<`?

Comment: @mark113 Думаю, что в разъяснении таких вещей лучше спросить @Abyx, т.к. я не уверен в своем ответе на 100%, поэтому пожалуй воздержусь от высказывания своей идеи :) @Abyx можете подсказать, что на самом деле делает компилятор, когда реализация оператора находится внутри класса с модификатором `friend` (раньше я никогда не пробовал реализацию функции писать там же где и само объявление другом внутри класса - я считал, что это вообще недопустимо!)?

Comment: @mark113 Я оформлю в виде ответа тогда, чтобы данный вопрос не оставался в списке не отвеченных, ок? (когда мне придет в голову однозначное пояснение или другие пользователи SO помогут грамотно пояснить, то распишем в ответе).

Comment: @StateItPrimitive конечно

Comment: @Abyx Хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функции определенные в теле класса при помощи `friend` не видны извне класса и могут быть найдены только при помощи ADL (поиска по типам аргументов).

Возьмем такой код:

```
struct A;

struct B {
    operator A();
};

struct A {
    friend void f(A) {}
    friend void g(B) {}
};

B::operator A(){ return A(); }

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;

    f(a); // OK
    g(b); // Ошибка

    f(b); // Ошибка
}
```

При вызове `f(a)`, функция `f` успешно находится т.к. она находится в наборе имен `A` (хотя ее полное имя это `::f`, но в процессе поиска имен можно считать что она находится в наборе имен `A`).

При вызове `g(b)`, происходит ошибка, т.к. `g` в `A` не видна, а в других пространствах имен такой функции нет (ни в `B`, ни в глобальном).

При вызове `f(b)`, происходит та же ошибка, т.к. `f` в `A` не видна, а в других пространствах имен ее нет (ни в `B`, ни в глобальном).
Оператор приведения типа тут просто не успевает сработать, т.к. компилятор даже не знает что `b` надо приводить к какому-то типу.

Так как в коде приведенном в вопросе ADL не возможен, то тело `operator<<` надо вынести из класса (можно оставить его другом).

Comment: Самое интересное в этом примере то, что студийный компилятор (по крайней мере от _visual studio 2010_ и _2013_) умудряется сделать неявные приведение типов и добраться до функции в единственном пространстве имен, где она реализована, в то время как `gcc` и `clang` выдают ошибку компиляции.

Comment: Причем, если скопировать реализацию, например, функции `g(B)` в класс `B`, то вылетает ошибка в духе `error: redefinition of 'g'` во всех трех компиляторах (от `MSVS`, `gcc` и `clang`). Начинает складываться впечатление, что это не _ADL_, как будто, ведь _ADL_ должно влиять лишь на поиск имени функции, указанного в выражении вызова функции, т.е. может влиять на ошибки компиляции в духе неоднозначности вызова функции, но не должен бы оказывать влияния на компиляцию определений функций с одинаковым прототипом в разных пространствах имен (независимо от их вызова), либо я чего-то недопонимаю :)

Comment: Хм, получается, что человек наткнулся на настолько узкий момент, что я очень удивлен. Но хорошо, что это выяснилось так сразу, буду знать на будущее :)

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо вынести реализацию

```
ostream& operator << (ostream &os, B const &s)
```

за пределы класса `B`, при этом оставив объявление данного оператора другом класса `B`:

```
class B
{
   public:
      // ...
      friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const B& s);
      // ...
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const B& s) 
{
   // ...
   return os;
}
```

Подробное разъяснение данной проблемы дано в ответе *Abyx*.

---

В следующий раз постарайтесь привести полный минимальный код (т.е. такой минимальный код, который скопировав в свой компилятор, любой пользователь SO сможет получить такую же ошибку), например [такой](http://ideone.com/QWWqWx), тогда мы сможем быстро предложить, например, [такое решение](http://ideone.com/mbbTYq).