# Неявное приведение типов в параметризованных классах

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
template <typename t_b> class B;
template <typename t_a> class A
{
   public:
    friend class B<t_a>;
    operator B<t_a> ();
};
template <typename t_b> class B
{
   public:
    B operator * (const B &s2) const {}
    friend class A<t_b>;
    A<t_b> operator [] (const B &s2) {}
};
template<typename t_a> A<t_a>::operator B<t_a> ()
{
    return B<t_a>();
}
int main()
{
   B<int> s1,s2,s3;
   s1[s2]*s3; // <-- ошибка
}
```

> [Error] no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'A' and
>   'B')

Почему не работает оператор приведения?

### **UPD**

Оказывается, вот это компилится

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename t_b> class B;
template <typename t_b> std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, const B<t_b> &s) 
{
} 
template <typename t_a> class A
{
public:
    friend class B<t_a>;
    operator B<t_a>();
};
template <typename t_b> class B
{
public:
    friend class A<t_b>;
    A<t_b> operator [] (const B &s2) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator << <t_b>(std::ostream &, const B &);
};

template <typename T>
B<T> operator*(const A<T>& s1, const B<T>& s2)
{
    return B<T>();
}

template<typename t_a> A<t_a>::operator B<t_a>()
{
    return B<t_a>();
}

int main()
{
    B<int> s1, s2, s3;
    std::cout << s1[s2] * s3;
}
```

Так что, возможно, проблема с другим связана

Comment: Такс, у меня тут появилось немного времени. Второй вариант кода, приведенный вами компилируется (хотя, на самом деле не в любом компиляторе, т.к. ваши `A<t_b> operator []` и `std::ostream& operator <<` ничего не возвращают, а должны бы) потому, что результатом выполнения операции `s1[s2] * s3` (после исправления в коде ошибки _ADL_) является класс `B`, а `std::ostream& operator <<`, принимающий экземпляр класса `B`, описан в глобальном пространстве имен. Почему он не должен компилироваться (ведь в нем не проявляется проблема, связанная с _ADL_)?

Comment: Можете еще, пожалуйста, привести минимальный полный код, не компилирующийся, о котором вы говорили через `friend` у операторов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вся проблема заключается в *ADL (Argument Dependent Lookup)*, если же вы `operator*` реализуете отдельно от класса, то проблема будет решена:

```
template <typename t_b> class B;

template <typename t_a> class A
{
public:
    friend class B<t_a>;
    operator B<t_a>();
};

template <typename t_b> class B
{
public:
    friend class A<t_b>;
    A<t_b> operator [] (const B &s2) { return A<t_b>(); }
};

template <typename T>
B<T> operator*(const A<T>& s1, const B<T>& s2){ return B<T>(); }

template<typename t_a> A<t_a>::operator B<t_a>(){ return B<t_a>(); }

int main()
{
    B<int> s1, s2, s3;
    s1[s2] * s3;
}
```

---

**Пояснение**

Операторы, определенные в теле класса, не видны извне класса и могут быть найдены только при помощи *ADL* (поиска по типам аргументов).

Оператор приведения типа тут просто не успевает сработать, т.к. компилятор даже не знает что экземпляр класса `A` необходимо привести к классу `B` (да и вообще, какому-либо классу), а реализация данного оператора находится именно внутри класса `B`.

Comment: А какой-нибудь другой способ есть? Просто у меня та же проблема с `friend` оператором `<<`, а для того чтобы его параметризовать, нужно вынести реализацию **перед** классом, как сказано в ответе ixsci http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495141/, получается такой способ не прокатит

Comment: @ZmitrikNikolay На счет `friend` и `operator <<` уже разбиралась данная проблема [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/498780/200756).

Comment: Не, у меня такая же ошибка, как в этом вопросе. Я так понимаю в http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498780/ имелось в виду вынести **за**, а тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495141/ **перед** - весело получается

Comment: Может мне как-нибудь переписать структуру классов, чтобы не возникало такой ситуации?

Comment: @ZmitrikNikolay Стоп, у вас не отрабатывает мое решение для заданного вопроса? Я проверил на 3ех компиляторах (_gcc_, _clang_ и _mvs_). На счет поменять структуру, сейчас подумаем стоит ли (кстати, вообще обычно стараются отделять от класса `operator+` `-` `*` `/` и все в этом духе, т.к. это нарушает принцип единой ответственности, хотя, по опыту скажу, что у всех разная точка зрения).

Comment: Ваше решение работает для операторов, которые не являются `friend`, а для `friend` при вынесении вниз "срабатывает" баг, описанный в http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495141

Comment: @ZmitrikNikolay Кстати, какой у вас компилятор, а то от этого зависит насколько сильно стоит заморачиваться со всякими этими `friend`? Сами видели в том сообщении сколько всяких багов в некоторых компиляторах повыскакивали :)

Comment: gcc, вот пытаюсь сейчас вставить перед классом `B` и выскакивает та же ошибка, что и в http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498780/, переставляю за - баг

Comment: в `VS15`, что перед, что после - отсутствует оператор `<<`, причём, что интересно, подчёркивает мой оператор приведения, мол его реализация не найдена

Comment: обновил вопрос, думаю стоит просмотреть реализации ещё раз. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @ZmitrikNikolay Меня тут пока что отвлекают, если не успею сегодня, то я еще завтра посмотрю и подумаю, ок? :) Если что (меня не будет вдруг), то вы сможете задать еще один вопрос на SO (новый вопрос), чтобы побольше людей подключилось к решению проблемы.

Comment: У Вас оператор преобразования не выполняется вовсе, т.к. левый аргумент у `operator*` имеет тип `A`, а не `B`, как у ТС. Да и ADL тут не при чём.

Comment: @alexolut Хм, а ведь если подумать, то и правда это немного другой случай, вот если бы свободная функция определялась бы внутри класса посредством `friend` (что-то в духе `fiend B operator*(const B&, const B&) { return B(); }`), вот тогда бы была ошибка из-за _ADL_. Вот только я теперь решил на минимальном примере с шаблонами посмотреть на ошибку и несколько ушел в [тупняк](https://ideone.com/Gb7rvD), не подскажете часом, что я там делаю не так? В моем примере выйдет такая же ошибка, если я напишу через `B<T> operator*(const B<T>& s1, const B<T>& s2)` и как раз будет приведение типов.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive в шаблонных функциях неявного каста параметров не делается. Когда добавляете нешаблонный оператор - начинает работать каст.

Comment: @alexolut Вот оно как, спасибо, приму к сведению.

Answer (score 2):

Начнем с того, что наличие шаблонных классов для проявления проблемы совершенно не нужно. Т.к. все члены открыты, то для уменьшения кода можно заменить `class` на `struct`, а `friend` убрать вообще. Дополнительно я добавил возвращение значений там где это требовалось. Получился следующий код:

```
struct B;
struct A
{
    operator B();
};

struct B
{
    B operator*(const B&) const { return B(); }
    A operator[](const B&) { return A(); }
};

A::operator B()
{
    return B();
}

int main()
{
   B s1, s2, s3;
   s1[s2] * s3; // <-- ошибка
}
```

Можно убедиться, что ошибка [осталась прежней](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/78GT0CQwEeWtxkp4):

> error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'A' and 'B')

Возвращаемся к самому вопросу:

> Почему не работает оператор приведения?

Не работает потому, что имеющаяся перегрузка `operator*` реализована как функция-член. Для нестатических функций-членов действует правило, что первый параметр (т.е. `this`) не может быть получен путем неявного преобразования из другого типа. Например, если поменять аргументы местами, т.е. использовать выражение `s3 * s1[s2];`, код [скомпилируется](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/YCtkdKAIuQPfavJV), т.к. на место левого операнда встал тип `B`, который не нужно преобразовывать, а правый операнд будет успешно неявно преобразован из типа `A` в `B`.

Чтобы исключить ошибку для исходного случая, надо реализовать `operator*` как [свободную функцию](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/IPe9TSkTvFCXdkjy):

```
B operator*(const B&, const B&) { return B(); }
```

Тогда неявные преобразования будут возможны для обоих операндов.

---

Однако, если итоговый вариант попытаться обобщить для шаблонных классов ошибка [проявится вновь](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5U2xVq00mW302rat). Причина тому - запрет выполнения неявных преобразований для аргументов шаблонной функции, т.е. нашего бинарного `operator*`. Чтобы эту ситуацию подправить, нужно перенести реализацию оператора в тело класса, сделав саму функцию нешаблонной (но в шаблонном классе `B`), и сохранить возможность по-прежнему принимать 2 явных операнда. Т.е. она не должна стать нестатической функцией-членом. Всё это достигается не совсем стандартным способом, путем добавления слова `friend` (несмотря на отсутствие необходимости иметь доступ к приватным данным (более подробно об этом можно почитать [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381164/friend-and-inline-method-whats-the-point) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890051/implicit-conversion-when-overloading-operators-for-template-classes)) ).

[Получим](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8UzzMYNJNHMujuwC) такую запись:

```
friend B operator*(const B&, const B&) { return B(); }
```

Б*о*льшая часть ошибок ушла, но одна, очень похожая на исходную, остаётся:

> error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'A<int>' and 'A<int>')

Т.е. компилятор не может найти `operator*`, если оба операнда имеют тип `A`.
Один из способов убрать эту ошибку - сделать оператор другом класса `A`:

```
friend B<T> operator*(const B<T>&, const B<T>&);
```

Правда при этом в g++ появляется [предупреждение](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VXlCK8AWREQvtZ4o), а clang вовсе [отказывается компилировать](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/LdPKqQX5kdNcUAVg).

Если [добавить явную реализацию](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fY3Qv3TbRTMRnjl3) для операндов типа `A`, ошибок и предупреждений не будет:

```
template <class T>
struct B;

template <class T>
struct A
{
    operator B<T>() const;
    friend B<T> operator*(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) { return B<T>(lhs) * rhs; }
};

template <class T>
struct B
{
    A<T> operator[](const B&) { return A<T>(); }
    friend B operator*(const B&, const B&) { return B(); }
};

template <class T>
A<T>::operator B<T>() const
{
    return B<T>();
}

int main()
{
    B<int> s1, s2, s3;
    s1[s2] * s3;
    s3 * s1[s2];
    s1[s2] * s1[s2];    
    s3 * s3;
}
```

Конечно, хотелось бы ограничиться одной реализацией `operator*` внутри `B` с возможностью неявного приведения типов. Не знаю, можно ли этого достичь в современном C++, [создал соответствующий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36021863/declare-non-template-friend-function-for-template-class-outside-the-class) на эту тему, правда, на английской части SO.