# no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'A<int>' and 'A<int>')

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
template <class T> struct B;
template <class T> struct A
{
    operator B<T>();
};
template <class T> struct B
{
    A<T> operator[](const B&) { return A<T>(); }
    friend B operator*(const B&, const B&) { return B(); }
};
template <class T> A<T>::operator B<T>()
{
    return B<T>();
}


int main()
{
    B<int> s1, s2, s3;
    s1[s2] * s3;
    s3 * s1[s2];
    //s1[s2] * s1[s2];//  <-- как сделать так, чтобы это работало (без повторных деклараций *)?  
    s3 * s3;
}
```

Comment: Знакомый код, [однако](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/503177/176217).

Comment: И зачем на каждый вопрос заводить нового пользователя?

Comment: @alexolut Да, но там это была функция-член, а теперь как свободная функция (назвал оператор функцией, чтобы не заморачиваться).

Comment: @StateItPrimitive у меня ссылка на мой ответ, а не на вопрос ТС :) так что там в коде уже свободная функция. Хотя не уверен, можно ли называть функцию `свободной`, когда она находится только лишь благодаря ADL.

Comment: @alexolut, если дубликат, то за как дубликат и закрывай. А так, причины закрытия непонятны.

Comment: @Qwertiy о чем речь?

Comment: @alexolut, где-то тут было "Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это дубликат" и 2 таких голоса. Или я путаю и это не в этом вопросе?

Comment: @Qwertiy вероятно, Вы что-то путаете.

Answer (score 3):

**Предложения по реазилации**

Вообще, стоит бы вынести реализацию свободного оператора

```
friend B operator*(const B&, const B&) { return B(); }
```

за пределы класса, т.к. получается, что он находится в его пространстве имен (если здесь это так можно назвать) и только за счет *ADL (Argument Dependent Lookup)* компилятор подбирает соответствующее пространство имен

```
s1[s2] * s3;
s3 * s1[s2];
```

в этих случаях за счет второго параметра, который, как раз, является экземпляром данного класса (класса `B`).

Но в этой строке:

`s1[s2] * s1[s2]`

оба аргумента оператора (`operator *`) являются экземплярами класса `A`. В итоге, компилятор не может вычислить необходимое пространство имен за счет аргументов данного оператора.

---

Но, с другой стороны, если вынести реализацию, то перестанут компилироваться и те 2 выше указанные строчки, т.к. в шаблонных функциях/классах неявного приведения типов параметров не происходит.

```
template <typename T>
B<T> operator*(const B<T>& s1, const B<T>& s2){ return B<T>(); }

template <class T>
struct B
{
    A<T> operator[](const B&) { return A<T>(); }

    friend B operator* <T>(const B&, const B&);
};
```

---

**Пути решения:**

1) Воспользоваться явным приведением типов:

```
static_cast<B<int>>(s1[s2]); // либо (B<int>)s1[s2]
```

---

2) Организовать `operator*` через базовый класс (`Base`) и наследовать ваши классы (`A` и `B`) от него:

```
template <class T>
struct Base{};

template <class T>
struct B;

template <class T>
struct A: public Base<T>
{
    operator B<T>();
};

// здесь, если понадобится, то закастуете типы
// ведь динамический тип параметров остался прежним
template <typename T>
B<T> operator*(const Base<T>& s1, const Base<T>& s2){ return B<T>(); }

template <class T>
struct B: public Base<T>
{
    A<T> operator[](const B&) { return A<T>(); }
    friend B operator* <T>(const Base<T>&, const Base<T>&);
};

template <class T> A<T>::operator B<T>(){ return B<T>(); }

int main()
{
    B<int> s1, s2, s3;
    s1[s2] * s3;
    s1[s2] * s3;
    s3 * s1[s2];
    s1[s2] * s1[s2];
    s3 * s3;
}
```

[Компиляция через gcc 5.1](https://ideone.com/0Tfc5H)

Answer (score 1):

Явно привести тип `A<int>` к `B<int>` (можно оба, можно только один) -

```
static_cast<B<int>>(s1[s2]) * static_cast<B<int>>(s1[s2]);
```

Такой вариант подходит?

Comment: Имхо, такой вариант нарушает естественность записи, о которой просит ТС.

Comment: @alexolut Тогда надо добавлять новые объявления, чего он категорически не хочет.

Comment: Тут ТС захотел даже больше, чем я. Меня бы устроил вариант без дополнительных определений. Хотя на объявления под каждый тип T я тоже не согласен.