# приведение типа в параметризованном `<<`

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Если реализовать `<<` после класса:

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename t_b> class B; 
template <typename t_a> class A
{
public:
    friend class B<t_a>;
    operator B<t_a>();
};
template <typename t_b> class B
{
public:
    friend class A<t_b>;
    A<t_b> operator [] (const B &s2) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator << <t_b>(std::ostream &, const B &); // <-- ошибка тут

};
template<typename t_a> A<t_a>::operator B<t_a>()
{
    return B<t_a>();
}
template <typename t_b> std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, const B<t_b> &s) {} 

int main()
{
    B<int> s1, s2, s3;
    std::cout << s1[s2];
}
```

> [Error] declaration of 'operator<<' as non-function

Если перед:

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename t_b> class B; 
template <typename t_a> class A
{
public:
    friend class B<t_a>;
    operator B<t_a>();
};
template <typename t_b> std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, const B<t_b> &s) {} 
template <typename t_b> class B
{
public:
    friend class A<t_b>;
    A<t_b> operator [] (const B &s2) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator << <t_b>(std::ostream &, const B &);

};
template<typename t_a> A<t_a>::operator B<t_a>()
{
    return B<t_a>();
}


int main()
{
    B<int> s1, s2, s3;
    std::cout << s1[s2]; // <-- ошибка тут
}
```

> [Error] cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}'
>   lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream&&'

Судя по ответам [Перегрузка операторов >> и << в шаблонном классе как дружественных функций](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495141) и [Возникает ошибка при неявном приведении типов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498780/) в первом случае имеет место баг `gcc`, а во втором - проблема с `ADL`. И решения получаются взаимоисключающими. Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело в том, что в шаблонных функциях/классах неявного приведения типов параметров не происходит, в связи с чем ваш

```
template <typename t_b>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, const B<t_b> &s) { return os; }
```

не может произвести неявного приведения типов от `A<t_b>` к `B<t_b>` в этом месте

```
std::cout << s1[s2];
```

---

Если же произвести явное приведение типов, то проблема исчезнет:

```
std::cout << static_cast<B<int>>(s1[s2]);
```

---

Также можно добавить явную специализацию шаблона (тогда будет работать без явного приведения типов) в стиле:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, const B<int> &s) { return os; }
```

Но я сомневаюсь, что такой способ решения проблемы вам подойдет (не добавлять же явную специализацию шаблона для каждого типа).

---

Либо можете воспользоваться [ответом *Harry*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/503241/200756) и реализовать перегрузку свободного оператора под класс `A` (сейчас у вас имеется реализация лишь под класс `B`, в связи с чем, компилятору необходимо производить приведение типов).

Answer (score 1):

Явное приведение типа должно спасти.
Или дописать

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, const A<T> &);
```

Comment: Куда дописать??

Comment: @ZmitrikNikolay Он к тому, что можно добавить переопределение свободного оператора `operator <<` явно под класс `A` (у вас же сейчас лишь под класс `B` он реализован), чтобы компилятору не приходилось выполнять приведение экземпляра класса `A` (результат работы `s1[s2]`) к классу `B`.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive ну если не будет других ответов, то так и сделаю, наверное

Comment: @ZmitrikNikolay Ну вы и правда подождите еще на всякий случай других ответов, вдруг мы что-то упускаем (мало ли).